# How to surpress Completed Stage: Warm Up and Completed Stage: Collection logs from Pytorch Profiler?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

Basically title. When running this code in a Jupyter notebook:

```
import torch
import torchvision.models as models
from torch.profiler import profile, ProfilerActivity

model = models.resnet18()
inputs = torch.randn(5, 3, 224, 224)

with profile(activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU], record_shapes=True) as prof:
    model(inputs)
```

the console prints

```
STAGE:2023-05-10 16:41:42 3392672:3392672 ActivityProfilerController.cpp:294] Completed Stage: Warm Up
STAGE:2023-05-10 16:41:42 3392672:3392672 ActivityProfilerController.cpp:300] Completed Stage: Collection
```

Is there a way to suppress these warning messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This was just recently fixed/added in a [pull request](https://github.com/pytorch/kineto/issues/726)

now you can set the env variable `KINETO_LOG_LEVEL`.
For example in a bash script: `export KINETO_LOG_LEVEL=3`

The levels according to the source code are:

```cpp
enum LoggerOutputType {
  VERBOSE = 0,
  INFO = 1,
  WARNING = 2,
  ERROR = 3,
  STAGE = 4,
  ENUM_COUNT = 5
};
```

Thats atleast how it should work, according to [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/kineto/issues/726) the changes for the log level have not been merged yet